# Copy Dynamic Range of Categories and Subcategories to Multiple Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a worksheet template that users can customize for their individual accounts. Each analyst has their own set of categories (Functional Areas) and subcategories (Cost Objects).

What I need to do is build a macro that will copy the list of Functional Areas to multiple sheets and autofill the Cost Objects underneath each Functional Area. The list of Functional Areas and Cost Objects will change for each user. The main list will look something like this:

```
Functional Areas         Cost Objects
```

```
 123456ABCD                40046748
 987654ZYXW                40046750
 456789WASD                40046751
 654321ORDL                40046752
                           40046753
                           40046754
```

The information copied to the other sheets needs to look like this:

```
Functional Areas         Cost Objects
```

```
  123456ABCD
                          40046748
                          40046750
                          40046751
                          40046752
                          40046753
                          40046754
```

```
 987654ZYXW
                          40046748
                          40046750
                          40046751
                          40046752
                          40046753
                          40046754
```

```
 456789WASD
                          40046748
                          40046750
                          40046751
                          40046752
                          40046753
                          40046754
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to do that with VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Since this will change for multiple users, you'll need to have some way of determining what functional areas and cost objects will be copied over for each user. There are several options:
1. Have this hard-coded directly in the VBA code.
2. Create a userform, with comboboxes or listboxes, so these elements can be selected in a user-friendly format.
3. Have a template worksheet with all functional areas, and all cost objects for each functional area. When a user is chosen, delete the unnceccesary data through a macro.

Comment: You're right. The way I've thought about tackling that problem is to build an array that will autofill a user's Cost Objects based on their organization's two-digit code. The users would then manually fill in a column of their Functional Areas since those can change from year to year.
After the lists are populated the user will hit a macro button to copy the lists to multiple worksheets they'll be using.